# How to convert time into seconds python?

Tags: python

Hello I am using the daytime module in python 3.3 to takeaway two times like this:

```
time_format = '%H:%M:%S'

total_time = datetime.strptime(time_left_system, time_format) - datetime.strptime(time_entered_system, time_format)
```

how would i convert this into seconds so i could print it like this?: 60 mph

Thanks

Comment: Have you read the docs for [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta)? It has a `total_seconds` method you might find useful. However, that gives you a *time*, not a *speed*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to want to use the [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) type from the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module, timedelta.total_seconds() will give you the time elapsed in seconds. you already have a timedelta by subtracting one datetime from the other, so you are set for the next step.
From there I don't know how you are converting it to mph, probably you are measuring against a fixed distance, just like people on the race track calculate with chronometers given the seconds a car took in a set track distance, but since you don't give the info on how you convert it I can't help you on that part.